# Select Case statment is chosing an unexpected condition when using enumeration

Tags: vb.net, enums, switch-statement

I have the following enumeration in some VB.Net code:

```
Private Enum DayOfWeek
    Sunday = 1
    Monday = 2
    Tuesday = 3
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 5
    Friday = 6
    Saturday = 7
End Enum
```

I then later have the following `Select Case` statement:

```
Dim weekDay As DayOfWeek

weekDay = DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Now)
Dim daysToAdd As Integer

Select Case weekDay
    Case DayOfWeek.Saturday Or DayOfWeek.Sunday
        daysToAdd = 0
    Case DayOfWeek.Thursday Or DayOfWeek.Friday
        daysToAdd = 4
    Case Else
        daysToAdd = 2
End Select
```

So when I run the code, `weekDay` is set to the correct value (5) for today (Thursday). However, when it hits the `Select Case` statement, it keeps selecting the `Case Else` condition instead of the `DayOfWeek.Thursday` condition and I can't seem to figure out why.

Does anyone see some glaring mistake that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Or statements for multiple Case options, use Commas.

```
    Select Case weekDay
        Case DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday
            daysToAdd = 0
        Case DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday
            daysToAdd = 4
        Case Else
            daysToAdd = 2
    End Select
```

Comment: You got it, awesome. Thanks! I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't try your code, but it looks like a casting problem, I know VB is very intellignt converting variables, but you should try cInt() to convert weekDay into a Integer.

Hope it helps, here's Microsoft Doc, https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/s2dy91zy.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but it was as @NoAlias's answer pointed out: I can't use `Or` in a `Case` statement, I have to use a comma instead.